# how can I color text of listview when i clicked on listview item and i want, when I clicked other items previous item should be the default color

Tags: android, listview

```
public void setDataToList() {
    liveTvAdapter = new LiveTvAdapter(this, channelList);
    horizonatalListViewForLiveTv.setAdapter(liveTvAdapter);

    horizonatalListViewForLiveTv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView textView;

            for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (position == i) {
                    textView = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.live_tv_chanel_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#63a0b9"));
                } else {
                    textView = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.live_tv_chanel_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }

            if (videoView != null) {
                videoView = null;
            }
            setValue(position);


        }

    });
}
```

this is above code that I am doing. Here i am getting textview from parent child from position. In this code when i clicked a third or fourth item , an item is not colored although other items gets colored.

Comment: using above logic may be can be done but this is not right way it can be slow. I posted right way which is fast as compare to above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer. I did it this way:-

first i made a method in my adaptor

```
 public void setSelectedIndex(int ind) {
            selectedIndex = ind;   // selectedIndex global variable
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

and than

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolderForLiveTV holderForLiveTV;
 if (selectedIndex != -1 && position == selectedIndex) {
                holderForLiveTV.channelName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#63a0b9"));
            } else {
                holderForLiveTV.channelName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
 return convertView;
}
```

and then I set the position of selected item like this way:-

```
liveTvAdapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Adapter's onClick you can use notifyItemChanged(oldPosition)

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int, java.lang.Object)
```